# Understanding the proof of Yoneda Embedding

Tags: category-theory, yoneda-lemma

### **Definitions**

Recently I was going through the proof Yoneda Embedding from Steven Roman's [An Introduction to the Language of Category Theory](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjM3sns9PLXAhUbSo8KHbIhCzAQFggmMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.springer.com%2Fin%2Fbook%2F9783319419169&usg=AOvVaw3Puy_uvo6Q-KYNF2qZB4KW). But before I go into the problem that I am having with the proof let me first state Roman's definition of an embedding (I do so because according to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedding#Category_theory) there is "no satisfactory and generally accepted definition of embeddings that is applicable in all categories").

> Let $\mathcal{C},\mathcal{D}$ be two categories and $F:\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{D}$ be a functor. Then,
>
> **Definition 1.** The restriction of $F$ to $\text{hom}_\mathcal{C}(A,B)$ as a *local arrow part* of $F$ and by the object part of $F$ we mean $F:\text{Obj}(\mathcal{C})\to\text{Obj}(\mathcal{D})$ where $\text{Obj}(\mathcal{C})$ and $\text{Obj}(\mathcal{D})$ denotes the set of objects of respectively $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$.
>
> **Definition 2.** $F$ is *full* if all of its local arrow parts are surjective.
>
> **Definition 3.** $F$ is *faithful* if all of its local arrow parts are injective.
>
> **Definition 4.** $F$ is *fully faithful* if all of its local arrow parts are bijective.
>
> **Definition 5.** $F$ is an *embedding* of $\mathcal{C}$ in $\mathcal{D}$ if it is fully faithful and the object part of $F$ is injective.

### **Background**

Now let me come directly to my problem. What I was going through is the following theorem (number unaltered),

> **Theorem 48**
>
> Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category. The contravariant functor $y: \mathcal{C} \to \sf{Set}^\mathcal{C}$ defined by,
>   $$y(A)=\text{hom}_\mathcal{C}(A,\cdot)$$and, $$y(h)=\{{h_X}^\rightarrow\}:\text{hom}_\mathcal{C}(A,\cdot)\to\text{hom}_\mathcal{C}(B,\cdot)$$for all $A\in\mathcal{C}$ and all $h\in\text{hom}_\mathcal{C}(B,A)$
>   is a contravariant embedding of $\mathcal{C}$ into the functor
>   category $\sf{Set}^\mathcal{C}$, called the **Yoneda embedding** of $\mathcal{C}$ in $\mathsf{Set}^\mathcal{C}$.

Where ${h_X}^\rightarrow:\text{hom}_\mathcal{C}(A,X)\to\text{hom}_\mathcal{C}(B,X)$ defined by, $${h_X}^\rightarrow(g)=g\circ h_X$$

In the proof he writes,

1. The object part of $y$ maps $A$ to $\text{hom}_\mathcal{C}(A,\cdot)$ and since $\text{hom}_\mathcal{C}(A,\cdot)$ and $\text{hom}_\mathcal{C}(B,\cdot)$ are distinct for distinct objects $A$ and $B$, the object part of $y$ is injective.
2. As to injectivity, if $y_{A,B}(h) = y_{A,B}(k)$ for $h,k: B \to A$, then
   $$\{h_X^\to:X\in\mathcal{C}\}=\{k_X^\to:X\in\mathcal{C}\}$$

   In particular, for the components associated with $X=A$, we can apply them to $1_A$ (the identity morphism from $A$ to $A$) to get
   $$1_A ∘ h = 1_A ∘ k$$
   and so $h = k$.

### **My Questions**

1. How does it follow that $A\ne B$ implies that $\text{hom}_\mathcal{C}(A,\cdot)\ne\text{hom}_\mathcal{C}(B,\cdot)$?
2. If $\{h_X^\to:X\in\mathcal{C}\}=\{k_X^\to:X\in\mathcal{C}\}$ then all we can say is the following, $$1_A ∘ h_Y = 1_A ∘ k_Z$$for some $Y,Z\in\mathcal{C}$. Why can we remove the subscripts?

Comment: 1) If $A\not = B$, no $f\colon  A \to X$  equals  any $ g\colon B \to X$, because  part of the defining data of a 'function' (ok, arrow) is its domain (ok, source). 2) You're being confused by the set notation $\{ \cdot \}$, I think. Think "components" $(\cdot, \cdots, \cdot )$. A function on a product space is equal iff it's equal on each of the components.

Comment: Namely, despite the notation, for each $X$, $h_X: {\rm hom} (A, X) \to {\rm hom} (B, X)$. It makes no sense to mix different components $X$ and $Y$, as you seem to be doing. In the case of the proof, the component is $X=A$.

Comment: Definitions 2 and 3 are wrong : 2 should be faithful and 3 should be full.

Comment: @ArnaudD.: Yes. You are right. Sorry for the typo.

Comment: @peterag Note that this works even if we don't explicitly include the domain as part of the data defining $f$: the domain is determined by its graph $\{\langle a, f(a)\rangle: a\in dom(f)\}$ (unlike the codomain).

Comment: @NoahSchweber - Perhaps I shouldn't have said 'function' - but I had wanted to bring the level of abstraction down. Still,  I really wanted the OP to think 'arrow,' which always comes with a specific source and specific target...

Comment: @NoahSchweber - and I always like trotting out, in this context, an old quote/quasi-joke of a category theory friend  of mine. "The Yoneda lemma is a tautology: the statement of Yoneda is 'An object is determined by the arrows from it.' The proof of Yoneda is 'in particular, it's determined by the identity.'"

Comment: So much about the terminology and notation here (presumably from Roman) makes me sad...

Comment: @peterag: I have understood your comment [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2552256/understanding-the-proof-of-yoneda-embedding?noredirect=1#comment5269025_2552256) as follows, please let me know if I have misunderstood your comment.

Comment: If possible let us suppose that $A\ne B$ but $\text{hom}_\mathcal{C}(A,\cdot)=\text{hom}_\mathcal{C}(B,\cdot)$. Then for all $X\in \mathcal{C}$ we would have, $$\text{hom}_\mathcal{C}(A,\cdot)(X)=\text{hom}_\mathcal{C}(B,\cdot)(X)\implies \text{hom}_\mathcal{C}(A,X)=\text{hom}_\mathcal{C}(B,X)$$for all $X\in\mathcal{C}$. However this would then imply that if $f\in \text{hom}_\mathcal{C}(A,X)$ we must also have $f\in \text{hom}_\mathcal{C}(B,X)$. In other words we must have both $f:A\to X$ and $f:B\to X$. However since each arrow has an unique source, we must have $A=B$, contradiction.

Comment: However I don't understand [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2552256/understanding-the-proof-of-yoneda-embedding?noredirect=1#comment5269060_2552256). Can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: See below for a response -

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - you understood my comment on 1. Point 2, is similar. Namely: Suppose we are given $h\colon B \to A$. Then $h$ induces, for *each* $X$, a  function $$h_X\colon {\rm hom} (A, X) \to {\rm hom }( B, X), $$ defined by the rule $ h_X (g) = g \circ h $. [No subscript on the right.]

*[ Continuing the proof of Yoneda - although you're not asking for it: ]*

Suppose we  are given 'another' morphism $k\colon B \to A$ (same source and target as $h$).

That means that we  now have, for  *each* $X$, two functions
 $$h_X,k_X \colon {\rm hom} (A, X) \to {\rm hom }( B, X). $$

But what  happens, if for *each* $X$, $h_X$ and $k_X$ coincide? That is, what happens if, for *each* $X$,  $$h_X = k_X?$$

Then the  previous equality holds, in particular, with $X=A$. That is,  $$h_A = k_A.$$

That means, for every $g\in {\rm hom} (A, A)$, that 
$$ h_A (g) = k_A(g),$$ or equivalently $g \circ h = g \circ k$. In particular, we can take $g= 1_A$. Therefore $1_A\circ h = 1_A\circ k$, and $h = k$ - and we are done.

To summarize: if $h_X=k_X$ for every $X$, then $h_A=k_A$, so that $h_A(1_A)=k_A(1_A)$, so that $1_A\circ h = 1_A\circ k$, so that $h=k$.

*[This answer was a follow-up to a comment above - but was itself too long for a comment.]*

Comment: Excellent!. That's exactly what I wanted. Many thanks also for continuing the proof of Yoneda Lemma (even though I didn't ask for that).

Comment: @user170039 I haven't listened to the following in a while, but I remember enjoying Eugenia Cheng's  cat theory lectures, and you might too: https://www.youtube.com/user/TheCatsters/videos

Comment: If $h_X=k_Z$ (using your notation) for some $X,Z\in\mathcal{C}$ then in particular for $X=A$ we would have $h_A=k_Z$ for some $Z\in\mathcal{C}$ and this would imply that $$h_A(1_A)=k_Z(1_A)\implies 1_A\circ h=1_A\circ k\implies h=k$$Is there anything wrong in this alternative argument?

Comment: I mind it because it doesn't make much sense to write $h_X= k_Z$ unless $X= Z$ - two functions can, a priori, only be compared (e.g. the above equal sign) if they have the same source and target, e.g.,   it makes no sense (without something else going on) to compare a function which takes  values in (or has as source) a finite field with another function which takes values in (or has as source)  three dimensional euclidean space. (cont)

Comment: (cont ) Likewise, I would say that it is syntactically incorrect to write "$h_Z(1_A)$"  unless  $Z=A$ to begin with, because $1_A$ is in the domain only of $h_A$. Do you see what I mean?  For instance, in a 'strict type' programming language, I would expect that "$h_Z(1_A)$" would give a compilation error. It might be interesting to try that out in Haskell - if that idea/test makes sense. I might try it out, or bring it up on the haskell stack exchange... If I do, I'll let you know.

Comment: I agree with everything that you said. My point simply was to assume that $h_X=k_Z$ for some $X,Z\in\mathcal{C}$ and then prove that $X=Z$ and finally conclude that (as you have done in your answer), $h=k$. (I reposted the comment because just now I noticed that I have made a typo in the now-deleted comment which needs to be corrected.)